# looking for MCR7.9 (for MATLAB R2008b

Tags: matlab

My m file was compiled by MATLAB R2008b. When I distributed it to others, their PC seem to lack certain DLL (mclmcrrt79.dll). Thus, I was looking for MCR7.9 but couldn't find any official copy. I did find some on the web: [MCR7.9 download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/expertomica-eda/files/Matlab%28R%29%20Compiler%20Runtime%207.9/) but am not sure whether it is safe to be installed. Is it OK to use this copy or is there any official MCR7.9 available?

Comment: Do the other users have [Matlab runtime](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/mcr/) installed on their machines? This is a standalone set of libraries that allow Matlab applications to be run without a full installation of Matlab.

Comment: I don't think the users installed MCR, so they got an error message saying that mclmcrrt79.dll is missed.

Comment: They need to install Matlab runtime. This is the official library that you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you Cecilia. I found MCR7.9.

Answer (score 0):

Since R2012a, the MCR for each version of MATLAB has been available as a [download](http://uk.mathworks.com/products/compiler/mcr/) from MathWorks.

Versions of the MCR prior to R2012a are not distributed in the same way by MathWorks, and should be distributed by the developer of the application along with the compiled component directly to end users. If you are the developer, you should distribute it along with the component - specifically, you should send them the MCR installer (you have this - it's in `\toolbox\compiler\deploy\<ARCH>`, where `<ARCH>` is your platform).

In fact, in R2012a there was a license-related change: for versions prior to that, you're not actually *allowed* to make the MCR (or the installer) available as public download (so the people who are making it available at the SourceForge site you link to are, strictly speaking, in breach of the license).

One other confusion may be causing you difficulty: R2008b is MATLAB version 7.7. MATLAB version 7.9 is R2009b. You need to make sure that you use the right version of the MCR for the version of MATLAB you used to compile.

Comment: Thank you, Sam. I found MCRInstaller per your instruction and sent it to the user. Now, there is no error message related to mclmcrrt79.dll. Unfortunately, the user saw another error message: 
"My Own Exception: Fatal error finding symbol mxCalcSingleSubscript_700 in D:\XYZ\libmx.dll Error:" 
Any suggestion?

Comment: @KYang What's "My Own Exception"? Is that shorthand for an error code generated by your application? If so, then it's just a problem with your code. But I'm surprised if your code might be generating messages referencing libmx.dll.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/169781/sam-roberts : when I ran the exe in my computer where it was compiled, nothing went wrong. But the error message appeared when the user ran the exe in his machine (Win 7 without Matlab). So I suspect it is the compatibility issue.

Comment: Again - what is "My Own Exception"? Did his computer have that text in its error message? If not, what was the actual error?

Comment: That is the exact error the user saw: "My Own Exception: Fatal error finding symbol mxCalcSingleSubscript_700 in D:\XYZ\libmx.dll Error:" Actually, I found a similar issue reported at http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/71749-please-help-standalone-application-not-working-on-windows-7. The problem is that it is somehow weird to ask the users to follow all the steps suggested by Friedrich before using the program.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, I solved the problem related to "My Own Exception: Fatal error finding symbol mxCalcSingleSubscript_700 in D:\XYZ\libmx.dll Error:" It was done by sending libmx.dll to the user. The file is stored at \MATLAB\bin\win32\